# ffmpeg slides to video with padding shows only one image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I usually create video clips of still images using something very similar to 
[This StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg). However, this time, I have a set of images of varying sizes, so clipped in options from [This OTHER StackOverflow example to pad the images to a set size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133242/ffmpeg-resize-down-larger-video-to-fit-desired-size-and-add-padding)
to come up with this:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i slide_%2d.png  -filter_complex "fps=25,format=yuv420p,scale=1024:768:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:768:x=(1024-iw)/2:y=(768-ih)/2:color=green" -y tmp.mp4
```

Of course it doesn't work as hoped, but this is the 21st Century, 'Google It' way!

What I'm attempting to do is create a command which feeds contiguously-numbered png images (starting at 01), in the current directory, at the rate of one per second, and outputs them as an mp4 file, suitably padded to a 16:9 ratio image size, with an eye-bleeding green background/surround (it's a test rig – I want to see what's what, quickly) at an arbitrary rate of 25 frames per second on the output (all 25 frames to be of the same input input image, of course).

What I get is the last frame of the image set for a duration that varies, depending on the contents of the -r flag.

Could somebody help me out here, please, and show me where I'm going wrong? I can spend delighted hours searching and tinkering, but I should be wasting my time on *other* fascinating projects now.

All the best,
QuinB

ffmpeg v. N-92396-g55e021f39b

OS Win10

Comment: Works here. Share full log.

Comment: Here y'go.
[tmplog_20181203a.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ydoqTAIqJwu9ULtKFzVQxuyYNXaer2YD)
Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Cutting back the command to:

    ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -i "test_%2d.png" "out03.mp4"

produces output showing multiple images viewable in ffplay (although, obviously, not scaled as required)

Adding in fps produces a short clip with a single image.

    ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -i "test_%2d.png"  -filter_complex "fps=25"  "out06.mp4"

omitting fps but scaling and formatting produces output showing multiple images

    ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -i "test_%2d.png"  -filter_complex "format=yuv420p,scale=1024:768" "out07.mp4"

Adding in 

force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease

gives 1 image

Comment: however, adding in the pad sequence creates an output showing multiple images.

    ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -i "test_%2d.png"  -filter_complex "format=yuv420p,scale=1024:768:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:768:x=(1024-iw)/2:y=(768-ih)/2:color=green" "out10.mp4"


"Eh, what?"

Comment: ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -i "test_%2d.png"  -framerate 25 -filter_complex "format=yuv420p,scale=1024:768:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:768:x=(1024-iw)/2:y=(768-ih)/2:color=green" "out15.mp4"


This produces output, as required, at 25fps

who knows why.

Comment: It shouldn't. Output should be 1. Run command with -report added and share report.

Comment: You. Are funny. If I had a  quid for every time I'd heard THAT line.
[log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ydoqTAIqJwu9ULtKFzVQxuyYNXaer2YD)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the log of the last cmd you posted. The log says of the input:  `Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1043x746 [SAR 23622:23622 DAR 1043:746], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc` i.e. 25 fps input.

Comment: Log submitted about should be output for the first command referenced in the post.


[Log for out15.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GHZb9d2-9SP2c_6SK32LaEWm7ZHAES8x)

Comment: Output is 1 fps: `Stream #0:0, 0, 1/16384: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1024x768 [SAR 190869:190976 DAR 63623:47744], q=-1--1, 1 fps, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc`.

Comment: quite right – my mistake.
ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -i "test_%2d.png"  -r 25 -filter_complex "format=yuv420p,scale=1024:768:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:768:x=(1024-iw)/2:y=(768-ih)/2:color=green" "out14.mp4"

produced 25fps. 
My apologies for posting incorrect information.